How to create generative method for deleteBy when a composite primary is present
I have these entity classes:
@Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HepatitisLabGroupTestTypePrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "lab_test_type")
    private String labTestType;

    @Column(name = "test_group_name")
    private String sortOrder;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupId;
}

and
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "hep_lab_group_test_type_order", schema = "nmi")
public class HepatitisLabGroupTestType {
    @EmbeddedId
    HepatitisLabGroupTestTypePrimaryKey id;
}

How do I make the generative deleteBy method, to delete by Group Id?
I tried:
  public void deleteByHepatitisLabGroupTestTypePrimaryKey_GroupId(Long groupId);
and
hepatitisLabGroupTestTypePrimaryKeyGroupId
and
deleteByGroupId
nothing worked.
Any pointers?

So I had a mistake here,
public void deleteByIdGroupId(Long groupId); OR
public void deleteById_GroupId(Long groupId);
